# JAVA stream corruption error (adding objects to file)

Tags: java

at the moment I'm trying to add objects to a file via an output stream, I'm able to successfully add an object to the file once then the file suddenly becomes corrupt when I reattempt to add another object, what could the issue be?

I'm trying to add a department object to a file so it can be later referenced such as updating the department and deleting it, the issue clearly is the way the output stream in inserting the data. Please read the below code.

I'm attempting to add an object to file which I'm expecting it to add to the file, as I previously stated I'm able to add an object to the file once but then the files become corrupt when I add to the file a second time

```
submitDepartmentButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
        {

            department new_dept = new department(DepartmentNameText.getText(),  
                    UserNameFeild.getText(), passwordLabel.getText());


             try {

                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Harry\\eclipse-workspace\\new assignment\\dept.dat", true);
                    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
                    oos.reset();
                    System.out.println("name for writing "+new_dept.getName());
                    oos.writeObject(new_dept);
                    oos.flush();
                    fos.close();
                    oos.close();
                } catch (EOFException ex) { 
                     System.out.println("End of file reached.");
                     } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                     ex.printStackTrace();
                     } catch (IOException ex) {
                     ex.printStackTrace();
                     }
```

Comment: What are you doing? What do you expect to happen? What happens instead? Be precise.

Comment: do you have an exmaple where it goes wrong as well ?

Comment: hi when i add to the file the first time the object adds successfully,  then when i reattempt to add to the file a second time a java.io.StreamCorruptedException: error appears

Comment: When you ask about an exception, always post the exact and complete stack trace of the exception. It tells what is wrong and where.